# 100% CPU usage when running SBT tasks in IntelliJ on Windows 10

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm running into an issue using IntelliJ on Windows 10 where running an SBT task appears to consume 100% of a core in a busy loop waiting for input. Has anyone else run into this issue?

#### JDK (Oracle 1.8.0_72, OpenJDK 1.8.x, Azul Zing)

`java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)`

`JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o`

#### Library Dependencies

- Scala 2.12
- sbt 1.0.4 (also occurs with 1.1.0)
- IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2 (Community Edition)
  Build #IC-173.4127.27, built on December 25, 2017

#### Expected Behavior

1. Run project using IntelliJ IDEA
2. Wait for compilation to complete
3. Project idles with little to no CPU usage

#### Actual Behavior

1. Run project using IntelliJ IDEA
2. Wait for compilation to complete
3. Project uses ~15 - 20% CPU (1 core on a Core i7 7700HQ) - 1 thread is in a tight loop that results in 100% usage of 1 core.

If I run the project via the SBT shell outside of IntelliJ (e.g. via the terminal), there is much lower CPU usage (~1-5% total, as opposed to ~20% in IntelliJ). If I run the project in the IntelliJ SBT shell prompt, I experience similar high CPU usage.

#### Thread profile

`sbt` -> `PlayConsoleInteractionMode`

[image]

#### CPU usage

[image]

Comment: Please raise a ticket at JetBrains tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL, providing a project example, and CPU snapshot like described here: 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235